# Source data showing up fine in power BI table but not pulling through to matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am currently working on building a P&L in Power BI to compare actuals to Budget. As seen in this this image below I have figures for all 12 months for Licence revenue but only figures for April are being pulled into the matrix. I have checked the spelling on all lines and the formatting is consistent so i am unsure as to why the matrix can pick up the April value fine but not the other 11 months.
My budget figures are related to the actuals using a treatas function (image also below). Can someone please help to explain why this is functioning on the majority of other lines but won't function in this situation?
[!Source data table in Power BI showin all 12 months (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTfLq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTfLq.png)
[image: Matrix visualisation pulling these figures into P&L (note Actauls have been removed from this but can be added in and this works perfectly fine]
[image: Treatas formula connecting budget to actual]

As mentioned above I have checked all dates to ensure they are in correctly, spelling and format of roll up is correct so should not cause any issues. Not sure what else to try as it is working in April so clearly there is something right here. Just not sure how to rectify the problem for the other months